# Linux: Wait for a PID to die

Tags: c++, linux, process, pid, epoll

I have a program with a central event mechanism that uses either select, epoll or kevent (platform dependend, OSX, Linux and FreeBSD).

Now I have a problem that I need to wait for a process to finish execution. All I got from this process is its PID. Is there a way to wait with the above mentioned mechanism for the PID to finish?

My current idea is to create a pipe for the PID and poll the PID by using `kill` with signal 0 to check if its alive. If not, write a byte to the pipe to wake up the polling mechnism. But I dislike the idea of needing an extra thread for this issue.

Thanks für every answer!

Comment: You can use ``waitpid`` (``man 2 wait``) to sleep until the process is finished.

Comment: But I want the rest of the program to be operational. Also I wont only wait for 1 pid, but multiple. Thats why I would like that in my polling mechanism.

Comment: You can have a pipe by process and push something into it at the end of the process. On the "master" process, you ``select`` on the pipe. Once a process finish, it write in the pipe. ``select`` stop waiting (since there is something to read in the pipe).

Comment: If the PID isn't your child, your design is racy, because such a PID is a moving target (PIDs get recycled). If the PID is your  child, you don't need to poll, because the kernel will notify you automatically by sending you the SIGCHLD signal and the PID will remain in limbo (as a zombie) until you reap it with a `wait*` syscall.

Answer (score 1):

Register a handler for SIGCHLD (empty one, you just want the signal to interrupt your call to select() or whatever other function you're normally waiting on), and then check whether the waiting function returned EINTR.  If so - it was interrupted by a signal; check the status of your children by calling wait4() with WNOHANG.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `waitpid` at the end of your execution. You can wait for multiple pid at the end of your program. Just store your pid in a `pid_t *` and wait for all of them (one by one). Your main process will wait for all his children so you will not have any zombie